# Use (write) SQL recursion to retrieve category level 2 in Hybris

Tags: java, sql, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a category organized by tree.
But the depth is not fixed.
When I have a child node.
So,How can I get category level 2 of the above node (also category).
Know that, Cat2CatRel (Category to Category Relation)is many to many.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data and the `create table` statements for the tables in question. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to find all categories with the parent category which is a root one?

Answer (score -1):

May be you can use java API :

```
List<CategoryModel> categories = category.getAllSubcategories();
categories.get(1);
```

Comment: Sorry.But I'm doing the report on Report Cockpit using Jasper Report?